# How do you Disable HTTP Request traces in Application Insights?

Tags: asp.net, azure-application-insights

I have a web service which polls another web service for data continuously.
I just upgraded the version of Application Insights I was using to:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.21.0" />
```

Now I have a continuous stream of HTTP events in my Azure event log that look like this:

```
9/17/2022, 1:37:31 PM - REQUEST
GET Orders/GetOrders [rowVersion]
https://development.thetarex.com/viewModel/quotes Request Code: 200 Response time: 4.8 ms
```

How do I get rid of these? I already have this in the settings file:

```
  "ApplicationInsights": {
    "EnableAdaptiveSampling": false,
    "EnableDependencyTrackingTelemetryModule": false,
    "InstrumentationKey": "0298fcb7-58c1-4a7f-9030-fe99f3a60504"
  },
```

But nothing seems to inhibit these HTTP event messages.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is having the same issue, I was almost there, just needed one more line in the appsettings file:

```
  "ApplicationInsights": {
    "EnableDependencyTrackingTelemetryModule": false,
    "EnableRequestTrackingTelemetryModule": false,
    "InstrumentationKey": "0198fcb7-58c1-4e7f-9030-fe99f3a60504"
  },
```

This seemed to clear out the Azure log so only my messages showed up.

Comment: what is the difference between answer's snippet and the one which apparently didn't work from your answer? They look the same to me.

Comment: Thanks for catching that. It was the **EnableRequestTrackingTelemetryModule** setting that turned off the logging of the Request events.